# Commerce Kickstart 2 - Views title not displayed

Tags: views, theming, commerce

When using views on Commerce Kickstart 2, the view title is not displayed. Is there any reason for such a behaviour, am I missing something?
The opening HTML is below.

```
    <div class="view view-videos view-id-videos view-display-id-page view-dom-id-8d05b9f39ee41546bd2d3d0540c05239">
     <div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
    <div id="node-video-page-13" class="ds-1col node node-video-page node-teaser contextual-links-region view-mode-teaser grid-4 node-not-sticky self-posted author-admin odd clearfix clearfix" style="background-color: rgb(224, 118, 40); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">

<div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed"><a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#">Configure</a><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="node-edit first"><a href="/node/13/edit?destination=welcome">Edit</a></li><li class="node-delete"><a href="/node/13/delete?destination=welcome">Delete</a></li><li class="manage-display last"><a href="/admin/structure/types/manage/video-page/display/teaser?destination=welcome">Manage display</a></li></ul></div>
```